# I booked an TGVAir train+plane ticket with Air France, must I travel the first (train) leg?

Tags: legal, france, sncf, air-france, tgvair

I have a booked TGVAir train+plane ticket with Air France. The problem now is that SNCF, the company that will effectively be handling my train journey, announced a train strike on my departure date. Therefore I am now looking to find other means of transportation to the airport (CDG) so that I don't miss the flight part of the journey.

Am I obliged to travel on the train part of the journey? Will my plane ticket be cancelled if I don't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a train+plane TGVAir journey, it seems that taking the train is mandatory to validate the electronic plane ticket for the second leg of the journey. Quoting from [the SNCF help page (in French)](http://aide.voyages-sncf.com/toute-laide-vol/je-reserve-mon-voyage/informations-sur-votre-voyage-bagage-assistance/reserver-un-billet-d-avion-avec-un-pre-acheminement-en-train-tgv-air):

> #### J’ai raté mon train ou je souhaite me rendre directement à l’aéroport. Que se passe-t-il ?
>
> Si votre voyage commence par un trajet en train, **il est impératif de vous présenter en gare de départ au comptoir TGV AIR pour valider votre billet électronique**.
>
> Dans le cas contraire, la compagnie aérienne se réserve la possibilité d'annuler l'ensemble de votre réservation, avec une pénalité pouvant aller jusqu'à 100 % du montant de votre billet.

Which roughly translates to:

> #### I missed my train and I plan to travel directly to the airport. What happens next?
>
> If your trip begins with a train journey, **it is mandatory to present yourself at the departure station TGV AIR counter to confirm your e-ticket**.
>
> Otherwise, the airline reserves the right to cancel your entire reservation, with a penalty of up to 100% of the cost of your ticket.

Comment: Note that [it might be possible to collect your ticket the night before](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30959/with-air-france-tgvair-can-you-check-in-the-night-before)

Comment: So you have to go to the train station and confirm your ticket - but do you actually have to get on the train?  Does anyone check that part?

Comment: @NateEldredge Given my recent experience I doubt that really happens. Indeed my train was an hour late, but soon after the original scheduled departure time I was allowed to check-in online on the plane leg of the journey. Hence by induction I would say that there's no actual check/coordination between the two services operating the train and plane leg of the journey. Rather it looks like a simple cron job.